# python mineflayer

Tags: python, бот, minecraft

создал бота

```
from javascript import require, On

 mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
 bot = mineflayer.createBot({
'host': 'какой то сервер',
'username': 'bot_test',
})

@On(bot, 'spawn')
def spawn_handle(*args):
    time.sleep(5)
    entity = bot.entityAtCursor()
    entity = entity2
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        bot.useOn(entity2)
        bot.attack(entity2)
        time.sleep(0.7)
```

и после 100 сек ошибка:

```
    [JSE] C:\Users\qwerty213\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\javascript\js\pyi.js:149
    [JSE]       throw new BridgeException(`Attempt to access '${stack.join('.')}' failed.`)
    [JSE]             ^
    [JSE]
    [JSE] BridgeException [Error]: Attempt to access '' failed. Python didn't respond in time (100000ms), look above for any Python errors. If no errors, the API call hung.
    [JSE]     at C:\Users\qwerty213\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\javascript\js\pyi.js:149:13
    [JSE]     at waitFor (C:\Users\qwerty213\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\javascript\js\pyi.js:46:26)
    [JSE]     at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    [JSE]     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:533:9)
    [JSE]     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
    [JSE]     at async PyBridge.call (C:\Users\qwerty213\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\javascript\js\pyi.js:148:18)
    [JSE]
    [JSE] Node.js v19.3.0
```

как я понял какой это то таймаут но какой и как его убрать я не понял искал искал но так и не нашел, пытался сам что то передать при создании бота но это тоже не увенчалось успехом

Немного про код чтобы не было вопросов зачем, почему,
бот заходит на сервер и перед ним стоит рамка он ставит в рамку предмет и сразу же выбивает дюп такой на сервере, почему entity равняется entity2 потому что иногда бот пытается поставить рамку на летящий предмет и его кикает с сервера, entity2 хранит информацию только о рамке в момент захода и все нормально работает. Я пытался сделать условие если entity = item то оно не будет работать но это не сработало как бы я не пытался

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего он ждёт завершения функции `spawn_handle` которая никогда не завершится. Будем смотреть когда у бота изменяется активный предмет и смотреть наличие предмета в рамке:

```py
import time

from javascript import require, On

mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    'host': 'Сервер',
    'username': 'bot_test',
})


@On(bot, 'spawn')
def spawn_handle(*args):
    entity = bot.nearestEntity(lambda entity: entity.name == "item_frame")

    @On(bot, 'heldItemChanged')
    def change_handle(*args):
        if (bot.heldItem is not None) and ((entity.metadata[8] is None) or (not entity.metadata[8].present)):
            bot.useOn(entity)
        else:
            bot.attack(entity)

    change_handle()
```

Также можно попробовать использовать просто nodejs:

```js
const mineflayer = require("mineflayer");


const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: "Сервер",
  username: "bot_test",
  auth: "offline",
});

bot.once("spawn", () => {

  await new Promise(function(resolve){ setTimeout(function() { resolve(); }, 10000); });

  var entity = bot.nearestEntity((entity) =>{return entity.name == "item_frame"});

  console.log(entity)

  bot.on("heldItemChanged", async () =>{
    if ((bot.heldItem) && (!entity.metadata[8] || !entity.metadata[8].present)){
      console.log("insert");
      bot.useOn(entity);
    }
    else{
      console.log("hold");
      bot.attack(entity);
    }
  });
  bot.useOn(entity);
});
```

Для запуска:

```
npm init
npm install mineflayer
node <Имя файла>
```

Comment: все равно ошибка с таймаутом

`BridgeException [Error]: Attempt to access '' failed. Python didn't respond in time (100000ms), look above for any Python errors. If no errors, the API call hung.`

Comment: @ВоваПрохоренко Вероятно ошибка как-то связана с настройками сервера для вашего кода действительно была ошибка спустя 100с, но для этого на моей конфигурации (1.20.1 (стандартный сервер без изменения конфигурации), python 3.11, node v18.18.0) ошибки нет. Можете сообщить какие-либо ещё отличия для возможности повторить данную ошибку? Возможно поможет перепись кода на nodejs.

Comment: Python 3.11.0
Node.js v19.3.0
server version 1.20.1 плагины есть но не знаю какие

Comment: @ВоваПрохоренко попробуйте запустить добавленный в ответ код

Comment: сделать бы так чтобы после захода скрипт засыпал секунд на 10 т.к на сервере есть лобби и задержка нужна

Comment: @ВоваПрохоренко добавил

Comment: ну его вроде не кикает но в рамку ставить он не хочет что то

Comment: @ВоваПрохоренко изначально предмет должен быть у бота в руке

Comment: в любом случае первоначальная проблема не решена и похоже что решения у нее нет, т.к даже поддержка в дискорде не смогла ничего ответить по поводу тайм аута